# StateHasChange dont want to rerender Select with new seleted

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have this dropdown that generates a couple of dropdowns.

it shows fine at first render. then i change a value that gives me back some new selected items for all the dropdowns.

problem is my StateHasChanged does not want to rerender correctly.

```
@foreach (Parameter parameter in @group.Parameters)
{
    @parameter.Description
    if (parameter.IsList == true)
    {
    //Create Dropdown List
        <select class="form-control" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs args) => SelectValueChange(args, parameter.Name))">
            @foreach (Element element in parameter.Domain.Elements)
            {                          
                <option selected=@element.IsSelected style="color:white; background-color:@element.State;" value=@element.Name>@element.Description</option>
            }
        </select>
    }                                        
    <br />
}
```

SelectValueChange is what i call when a new option is selected.

```
private void SelectValueChange(ChangeEventArgs args, string selectName)
        {
            var selectedName = args.Value.ToString();
            ValueChange(selectName, selectedName);
        }
```

ValuChange is where im trying to force the rerender.

```
public void ValueChange(string param, string value) 
        {     
            Result newResult = config.Commit(param, value);
            SetupPage(newResult);
           
            //TODO: find a way to change these values newResult.Response.Changed or newResult.Response.AllChanged
            ShowNotification(newResult.Response);

            InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
```

SetupPage is where im just settings the new values from my result. maybe i can set these in a different way?

```
private void SetupPage(Result result) 
        {
            CurrentStep = null;
            Headline = null;
            Groups = null;
            PrevSteps = null;
            NextSteps = null;

            CurrentStep = result.CurrentStep;
            Headline = result.RootGroup.Description;
            Groups = result.RootGroup.SubGroups;
            PrevSteps = result.PreviousSteps;
            NextSteps = result.NextSteps;
            StateHasChanged();
            
        }
```

Comment: So far i can make it 'work' if i introduce a await Task.Delay(250); and then call my StateHasChanged.. But i wish i knew a way to know when its done updating the 'new result'

Comment: Try using "async Task" instead of void on your methods and await each call.